# php variable in mysql statement...how do I do it

Tags: php

```
 <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("names") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $green = "rose";    

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name = '"$green"'); 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
     Print "<tr>"; 
     Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> "; 
     Print "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['pet'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     Print "<th>Color:</th> <td>".$info['fav_color'] . "</td> "; 
     Print "<th>Food:</th> <td>".$info['fav_food'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

The above code works fine until I try and replace the name= in the SELECT statement with
the variable I created above $green = 'rose'.It wont take the variable the way I put it in the  SELECT statement.Is there a special way of placing variables in a select statement.?
Many thanks
jim

Comment: Your table name is mispelled.

Comment: You should really get away from mysql, use PDO or MySQLi as I put in my answer below.  You should also learn to use prepared queries to prevent SQL injections for user inputted variables like POST/GET etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the additional quotes:

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name = '"$green"');
```

becomes

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name = '$green'");
```

or

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name = '" . $green . "'");
```

It is also appropriate to mention that mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and you should look to update your code to use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL

Comment: Additionally, you can also concat if you want to keep your quotes

Comment: Please mention that mysql_query is deprecated

Comment: Added deprecation data

Answer (score 1):

Try this->

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name = '$green'");
```

Comment: This should be the one you need

Answer (score 0):

You should get away from mysql as the mysql API is deprecated.

You can use PDO or MySQLi, I prefer PDO since it supports more than just MySQL.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
```

To use a standard query, you can do:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name = '".$green."'");
```

But for most variables, especially user inputed fields, you should use prepared queries.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($green));
```

This query is protected from SQL injections.

To obtain multiple results you could run:

```
while ($info = $stmt->fetch()) {

     Print "<tr>"; 
     Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> "; 
     Print "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['pet'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     Print "<th>Color:</th> <td>".$info['fav_color'] . "</td> "; 
     Print "<th>Food:</th> <td>".$info['fav_food'] . " </td></tr>"; 

}
```

Here is a nice tutorial for PDO: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: many thanks for this I am working my way through the tutorial